# What should 4 say?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

Another fun one for you:

What should number 4 be?

One is VERA

Two is VERA and ENID

Three is VERA and ENID and RITA

What should number four be?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll go with

> Adam

because

> ```
>  V E R A
>  E N I D
>  R I T A
>  A D A M
> ```

Comment: Fbhaqf yvxr vg pbhyq or `NQN_` jvgu nalguvat nf vgf sbhegu naq ynfg yrggre?

Comment: Sure. Pick whatever you feel would be a more fitting choice.

Answer (score 11):

I think 4 is:

> ADAM
>
>  or more exactly: VERA, ENID, RITA, ADAM

Because:

> If you write the four names below it each others
>  they can be read horizontally as well as vertically
>
>  `VERA`
>  `ENID`
>  `RITA`
>  `ADAM`